# find the domain of this function null set

Tags: real-analysis

S I have this function here:

$$\frac{ \ln(1-\sqrt{x^2+1}) }{\sqrt{(\arctan(x)-\frac{ \pi }{ 4 })(\arctan(x)-\frac{ \pi }{ 3 }}) }$$

and I am asked to find the domain of this function. Normally, this would not be very hard for me but I'm a little bit confused.

If I plot this, I can see the function being graphed (Not a complex plot) but I use software to find the domain, I get the null set. Why is that? Does this function even have a domain?

Comment: How exactly did you "plot" it?

Comment: If we are talking about real-valued function, I suppose we must have $1 > \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$, which does not seem possible to me.

Comment: Ohh I just put it on Wolfram.

Comment: Yeah I see that too. It could just be wolfram being wrong?

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty No. The "domain" you are talking about should be shown under "Properties as a real function" on that page.

Comment: What about this?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(1-sqrt(x%5E2%2B1))%2F(sqrt((arctan(x)-pi%2F4)(arctan(x)-pi%2F3))

Comment: You say "not a complex plot", but those plots show real parts and imaginary parts...

Comment: I swear I am dead right now. I forgot that a complex number is f(x)=a+ib and forgot the real parts are plotted too. Thanks >.< .

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty Well, guess that's why mathematicians have to be careful with computers :p

Comment: Indeed they do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = \ln\left( 1-\sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right)$. We see that this function is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$, since we can never have $1 > \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$.

However, in complex analysis, we *can* define logarithm of any complex number by

$$Log(z):=\ln|z| + i\arg(z)$$

In this case, we essentially have

$$Log(1-\sqrt{x^2 + 1})=\ln\bigl|1-\sqrt{x^2 + 1}\bigr| + i \arg\left(1 - \sqrt{x^2 + 1}\right)$$

As you can see, we have a "real part" and an "imaginary part". On the graph output, you should be able to see these two different parts.

Comment: Yes. I forgot that the function has real AND imaginary parts >.< . Thanks...